# Recreate a file which was onece 301 redirected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

If I have a file named `/a.php`, and with `.htaccess` I redirected that URL to `/b.php` with `301` flag. For the SEO sake, I have to use `301` flag. But what if I need to get back to `/a.php` ??? Browser which once faced that `301` redirect will remember this and do redirect until the remove cookies themselves. So What should be my plan???

Comment: For SEO sake don't go back to `/a.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if I need to get back to /a.php ???

Then you remove the 301 redirect *to the `b.php` file* and create a new 301 redirect *to the `a.php`* file when the `b.php` file is requested. Even if browsers remember that a->b, when the browser requests b.php, it'll be 301 redirected back to a. As long as the old 301 redirect isn't there, the browser will then try to load a.php.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question. If I want to keep both `b.php` and `a.php` after some time?

Comment: @HasibAlMuhaimin No idea what you are trying to accomplish here, but you can keep both of them around, and redirect one to the other or vice versa, but it's generally not good for your SEO if you keep changing this stuff around